# Puppet lookup fails to find hiera key value

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm seeing this error with my puppet lookup call (basic test using hiera):

```
puppet lookup --explain foo

Searching for "lookup_options"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    No such key: "lookup_options"
Searching for "foo"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    No such key: "foo"
Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'foo'
```

Trying a direct hiera lookup works:

```
hiera -d foo
DEBUG: 2019-01-16 11:53:39 +0000: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2019-01-16 11:53:39 +0000: Looking up foo in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2019-01-16 11:53:39 +0000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2019-01-16 11:53:39 +0000: Found foo in common
bar
```

My hiera.yaml file (located in /etc):

```
---
version: 5
hierarchy:
  - name: Common
    path: common.yaml
defaults:
  data_hash: yaml_data
  datadir: data
```

My common.yaml file (located in /var/lib/hiera):

```
---
foo: bar
```

Can anyone explain why I'm seeing this error (fairly new to Puppet) ...

Comment: Based on the above I can't reproduce it, so you must have an issue like a file in the wrong place etc. If you provide more info on the file locations we can probably help.

Comment: thanks - edited topic to add file locations

Comment: Those are weird locations for your hiera config and your data. Any reason not to use the supported locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a file location problem.

I have:

```
▶ cat spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml 
---
version: 5
hierarchy:
  - name: Common
    path: common.yaml
defaults:
  data_hash: yaml_data
  datadir: data
```

Structure:

```
▶ tree spec/fixtures/hiera
spec/fixtures/hiera
├── data
│   └── common.yaml
└── hiera.yaml
```

Command line:

```
▶ puppet lookup --hiera_config=spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml foo 
--- bar
```

Note that the `data` directory as referenced in `hiera.yaml` in `defaults.datadir` must be relative to the directory your `hiera.yaml` is in. [Ref](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_config_yaml_5.html):

> datadir — The directory where data files are kept; can be omitted if you set a default.
>
> This path is relative to hiera.yaml’s directory: if the config file is at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera.yaml and the datadir is set to data, the full path to the data directory is /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/data.
>
> In the global layer, you can optionally set the datadir to an absolute path; in the other layers, it must always be relative.

Comment: thanks - I don't see the --hiera_config option for puppet lookup though (I'm using puppet 4). How would that be specified for v4?

Comment: @bzo You do not need that flag. He was using it because his config was in a test location. You should put your config in the supported location since you are executing on the master.

Comment: The same flag should work in Puppet 4. As Matt said you probably don’t want to use it in your set up. See docs https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/configuration.html#hieraconfig